# CoreData - Only fetch specific child managed Objects using a generic method

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a strange problem:

I have a `NSManagedObject` called `ItemTemplate`. It has many child managed objects, e.g. `CustomItemTemplate` or `SpecialItemTemplate`.

Now I have a list `viewController` that is supposed to show these child managed objects. For example only "CustomItemTemplaze" or only "SpecialItemTemplate". I wrote this generic method to fetch all `ItemTemplate`s and filter out the desired child-objects (I haven't found a better way yet).

```
private func loadTemplates<T: ItemTemplate>(ofType type: T.Type) -> [ModelObject] {
    // ModelObject is just a model for my managed objects
    var templates = [ModelObject]()

    do {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<ItemTemplate> = ItemTemplate.fetchRequest()
        let result = try mainViewContext.fetch(request)

        for item in result {
            if item is T { // this is somehow always true
                templates.append(item.modelObject) // add the converted item to the array
            }
        }


    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: ", error.debugDescription)
    }

    return templates
}
```

I call it like this:

```
enum Category {
    case custom
    case special

    public var templateClass: ItemTemplate.Type {
        switch self {
        case .custom:
            return CustomItemTemplate.self
        case .special:
            return SpecialItemTemplate.self
        }
    }
}


loadTemplates(ofType: currentCategory.templateClass)
```

However, it's not filtering. `if item is T` seems to be true for every item. It thus returns every `ItemTemplate`, instead of only certain child objects.

Why is that? I can't explain it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does the `ìf item is T`-check work if you give `CustomItemTemplate.self` or `SpecialItemTemplate.self` directly instead of giving the type ItemTemplate?

Comment: Yes, it works when I do it directly

Comment: So the generic  function gets called with ItemTemplate.Type, thats probably why the generic function uses that for comparison in your example above.

Comment: Hmm, that's possible. Strange. Would there be another way of doing what I want to do?

Comment: I don‘t think so. The compiler has for some reason to know what type to use when instantiating generic(a function here), so it takes what it got. Probably has to do with that return values and inside instantiating arrays of the generic type are things it wants to set in stone instead of determining that kind of thing at runtime. Probably something about Swift being a strictly static language. You can still do a switch on Category though, just put the content of the computed property outside and call loadTemplates in the appropriate cases with the appropriate type.

Comment: Okay, that could be it. That's a good idea, thanks!